# Cant view my site in Joomla 3.1.5

Tags: view, joomla, preview

I have done all tutorial step by step but when i click on preview site or just site it opens my localhost totally different maybe problem in WAMP server?Here is the link http://www.files.kg/file/8g2/Screen_Capture_%23307.png

Comment: Under "Your Projects", where are all the files such as index.php and config.php?

Comment: They exist in C actually but they invsible in localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WAMP server-www folder there is a default index.php that generated page you have shown. 
If you want your Joomla installation directly in the root 'www' folder you need to remove the default index.php and replace it with that of joomla.